# a counting problem on lattice

Tags: set-theory, discrete-geometry, euclidean-lattices

In $d$-dimensional lattice, we define a set $S_0$ be the zero point.

At step $i\geq 1$:

For each point $p\in S_{i-1}$, we can choose a single point $q$ who is a neighbour of $p$, and add $q$ into $s_{i-1}$ to obtain $S_i$.

Can we have a closed form for

$a_i=\max |S_i|$

for each $i$?

How about $d=2$?

It is clear that $a_1=2, a_2=4,a_3=8,a_4=16$ for any $d\geq 2$.

Comment: "It is clear that $a_1=2, a_2=4,a_3=8,a_4=16$ for any $d$." -- Not true for $d=1$.

Comment: @Pinelis Thank you!!!